# Kubernetes Ingress does not work with traefisk

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I created a kubernetes cluster in Google Cloud Platform, after that, I installed Helm/tiller on cluster, and after, I installed traefik with helm like oficial documentation says to do.

Now i'm trying to create an Ingress for a service, but if I put the annotation `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik`, the load balancer for Ingress is not created.
But without the annotation, it works with default Ingress.
(The service type is nodeport)

EDIT: I also tried this example in a clean google cloud kubernetes cluster: https://supergiant.io/blog/using-traefik-as-ingress-controller-for-your-kubernetes-cluster/ but its the same, when I chose `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik`, won't be created a load balancer for ingress.

my files are:
`animals-svc.yaml:`

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: bear
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: http
    targetPort: 80
    port: 80
  selector:
    app: animals
    task: bear
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: moose
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: http
    targetPort: 80
    port: 80
  selector:
    app: animals
    task: moose
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hare
  annotations:
    traefik.backend.circuitbreaker: "NetworkErrorRatio() > 0.5"
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: http
    targetPort: 80
    port: 80
  selector:
    app: animals
    task: hare
```

`animals-ingress.yaml:`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: animals
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "my-reserved-global-ip"
    # traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/frontend-entry-points: http
    # traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-entry-point: http
    # traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-permanent: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hare.minikube
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: hare
          servicePort: http
  - host: bear.minikube
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: bear
          servicePort: http
  - host: moose.minikube
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: moose
          servicePort: http
```

`animals-deployment.yaml:`

```
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: bear
  labels:
    app: animals
    animal: bear
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: animals
      task: bear
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: animals
        task: bear
        version: v0.0.1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: bear
        image: supergiantkir/animals:bear
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: moose
  labels:
    app: animals
    animal: moose
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: animals
      task: moose
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: animals
        task: moose
        version: v0.0.1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: moose
        image: supergiantkir/animals:moose
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: hare
  labels:
    app: animals
    animal: hare
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: animals
      task: hare
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: animals
        task: hare
        version: v0.0.1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hare
        image: supergiantkir/animals:hare
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

The services are created, but the ingress loadbalancer is not created:

[image]

But, if I remove the line `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik` it works with the default ingress of Kubernetes

Comment: why do you think kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik should create loadballancer for you? This is kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce who created loadballancer for you, but not traefik

Comment: Wow! Really? I read "When you create an Ingress object, the GKE ingress controller creates a Google Cloud Platform HTTP(S) load balancer and configures it according to the information in the Ingress and its associated Services." here: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress Then I though that with traefik I also need to write the Ingress and the loadbalancer will be automatically created... Then, with traefik, should I change services from NodePort to LoadBalancer? Or should I create services with NodePort and after I create a Load Balancer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traefik does not create a load balancer for you by default.

As [HTTP(s) load balancing with Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress) documentation mention:

> When you create an Ingress object, the GKE ingress controller creates
>   a Google Cloud Platform HTTP(S) load balancer and configures it
>   according to the information in the Ingress and its associated
>   Services.

This is all applicable for  GKE ingress controller(gce) - more info about gce you can find here: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce

If you would like to use Traefik as ingress  - you have to  expose Traefik service with `type: LoadBalancer`

Example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

More info with a lot of explanation diagrams and real working example you can find in the [Exposing Kubernetes Services to the internet using Traefik Ingress Controller](https://technology.amis.nl/2019/03/08/exposing-kubernetes-services-to-the-internet-using-traefik-ingress-controller/) article.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add more annotations as below

```
traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/frontend-entry-points: http,https
traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-entry-point: https
traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-permanent: "true"
```

Like this,

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: traefik-dashboard-ingress
  namespace: traefik
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/frontend-entry-points: http,https
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-entry-point: https
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-permanent: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: traefik-ui.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: traefik-dashboard
          servicePort: 8080
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Can you run this example in your google cloud kubernetes? https://supergiant.io/blog/using-traefik-as-ingress-controller-for-your-kubernetes-cluster/ I'm trying without success. The load balancers for ingress are never been created

Comment: Where's type "NodePort" in your service file ?

Comment: Oh, I saw two services "NodePort" were created. If you want to use LoadBalancer, you can change type: LoadBalancer instead of NodePort.

Comment: Refer this url to understand LoadBalancer https://codeburst.io/google-kubernetes-engine-by-example-part-2-ee1f519a32f9,
And this one to understand NodePort + Ingress: https://codeburst.io/google-kubernetes-engine-by-example-part-3-9b7205ad502f

Comment: Yes, I solved, with traefik you don't create a load balancer per ingress, but with default gce ingress controller, you have a different load balancer per ingress, I didn't understand well the difference ate the beginning. Now I only have one LoadBalancer that is for traefik "proxy", and all other services pass there.